# Is an SLX M7000 crankset compatible with the rest of my drivetrain?

Tags: shimano, crankset, compatibility, sram

I ride a [Comencal Meta HT AM Origin](https://tech.commencal.com/bike/META-HT-AM-ORIGIN-650B-RED-2016/10.html). Unfortunately I need to buy a new crankset. I’ve been thinking about [Shimano SLX FC-M7000](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/slx-m7000/FC-M7000-11-2.html) 34-24T with a new bottom bracket, BB-MT800.

Do you know if that crankset will work fine with the SRAM x5 parts which are currently on my bike?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Whether or not something is "good" is mostly a matter of opinion, so I edited that out of your question. The compatibility aspect is definitely a Stack Exchange sort of question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there would be any problems mixing SRAM and Shimano per se. The SLX crank is a higher end component than the X5, so you would be buying more than you need, and you get problems mixing 9 and 11 speed components.

- The 11 speed SLX crank uses a narrower chain than 9 speed. The 11 speed chainrings are slightly closer together which may give you shifting problems and chain rub as your front derailleur is designed for 9 speed chainring spacing.
- By choosing a 24/32 crankset instead of 22/36 you'll be loosing high and low ratios. The smaller chainring gap on the SLX is made up for by a wider spread of sprocket sizes available in 11 speed cassettes.

Upgrading one component several steps - even something major like the crankset - does not make a significant difference to the bike overall, and here you'd be introducing other problems. Better to play it safe and get a SRAM crank. I think all SRAM X-5 through X-9 cranks are now nominally 10 speed but each line includes 9 speed rear derailleurs so they should work fine for you.